# What is the maximum time.Time in Go?

Tags: date, time, go

I'm looking for documentation on the Max time.Time in go.

Other languages make it explicit, for example in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public static readonly DateTime MaxValue
```

> The value of this constant is equivalent to 23:59:59.9999999, December
>   31, 9999, exactly one 100-nanosecond tick before 00:00:00, January 1,
>   10000.

What is the maximum time.Time in Go? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: time.Time is backed by a int64: http://golang.org/src/pkg/time/time.go#L34

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Time in go is stored as an int64 plus a 32bit Nanosec value (currently a uintptr for technical reasons), so there's no real worry about running out.

```
t := time.Unix(1<<63-1, 0)
fmt.Println(t.UTC())
```

prints `219250468-12-04 15:30:07 +0000 UTC`

If for some reason you want a useful max time (see [@cce's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32620397/32880) for details), you can use:

```
maxTime := time.Unix(1<<63-62135596801, 999999999)
```

Comment: Haha, that's awesome to know. Y292277026596 problem!

Comment: @twotwotwo Actually, it occurs before `292277026596-12-04 15:30:07.999999999 +0000 UTC` - check out http://play.golang.org/p/O8A2QhQLka

Comment: @Momer Ah, exciting! Futzing with your example it looks like I need to make an appointment for `219248499-12-06 15:30:07.999999999` on my calendar then (what I get by subtracting unixToInternal from the seconds to make the comparison w/1970 go right: http://play.golang.org/p/i6S_T4-X3v). Learn something new every day!

Comment: Be sure to see cce's answer if you are going to be doing .Before / .After comparisons.

Comment: @KyleBrandt: oh thanks, I forgot to fix this up a long time ago.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `math.MaxInt64`

Comment: As noted by cce below (and the edited community answer), 1 << 63 -1 is not a valid max time -- in fact time treats it as a negative number.  Comparisons break and the documentation on time.Unix()  explicitly states: "Not all sec values have a corresponding time value. One such value is 1<<63-1 (the largest int64 value)".  Personally I just use 1<<62, which is large enough for practical purposes

Answer (score 40):

`time.Time` in go is stored as an int64 plus a 32-bit nanosecond value, but if you use @JimB's answer you will trigger an integer overflow on the `sec` component and comparisons like `time.Before()` will not work.

This is because `time.Unix(sec, nsec)` adds an offset of 62135596800 seconds to `sec` that represents the number of seconds between the year 1 (zero time in Go) and 1970 (zero time in Unix).

@twotwotwo's playground example makes this clear in http://play.golang.org/p/i6S_T4-X3v but here is a distilled version.

```
// number of seconds between Year 1 and 1970 (62135596800 seconds)
unixToInternal := int64((1969*365 + 1969/4 - 1969/100 + 1969/400) * 24 * 60 * 60)

// max1 gets time.Time struct: {-9223371974719179009 999999999}
max1 := time.Unix(1<<63-1, 999999999)
// max2 gets time.Time struct: {9223372036854775807 999999999}
max2 := time.Unix(1<<63-1-unixToInternal, 999999999)

// t0 is definitely before the year 292277026596
t0 := time.Date(2015, 9, 16, 19, 17, 23, 0, time.UTC)

// t0 < max1 doesn't work: prints false
fmt.Println(t0.Before(max1))
// max1 < t0 doesn't work: prints true
fmt.Println(t0.After(max1))
fmt.Println(max1.Before(t0))

// t0 < max2 works: prints true
fmt.Println(t0.Before(max2))
// max2 < t0 works: prints false
fmt.Println(t0.After(max2))
fmt.Println(max2.Before(t0))
```

So while it is a bit of a pain you can use `time.Unix(1<<63-62135596801, 999999999)` if you want a max `time.Time` that is useful for comparisons like finding the minimum value in a range of times.

Answer (score 7):

Note that, although @cce's answer ensures `After` and `Before` will work, other APIs won't. `UnixNano` only works within ±292 years around 1970 (between 1678 and 2262). Also, since maximum duration is ~292 years, even those two will give a clamped result on `Sub`.

So, an alternative is to pick a minimum<sup>[1]</sup> value and do:

```
var MinTime = time.Unix(-2208988800, 0) // Jan 1, 1900
var MaxTime = MinTime.Add(1<<63 - 1)
```

Within these, everything should work.

[1]: An other obvious choice is `time.Unix(0, 0)` if you don't care about dates before 1970.